# Index out of bounds in a for loop but (wrong) working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

This is my first question here, so sorry if I don't proceed correctly. Tell me if this happens.

I'm getting crazy with a ridiculously easy for loop.

Variable `res` is the response of a sql query, where IDs that meet the condition are saved as a JSON array. `JSON.stringify(res)` returns `[{"id":1},{"id":2}]`. Here is the code:

```
    for(var ii = 0; ii <= res.length-1; ii++){
        console.log("res[ii].id: "+res[ii].id); //throws the correct message on console, so ii=1 first and later ii=2.

        laDatabase.all("SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Movies.id="+res[ii].id+";", function(err, resMovies){
            console.log("resMovies: "+JSON.stringify(resMovies)); //throws the correct message on console, the sql sentence is correct and runs without problem
            if(err){
                console.log("Error en 'SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Movies.id="+res[ii].id+";'");
                return;
            }else{
                //I tried to move the response of the sql query to the array I'll return. At this point, ii=2 always
                console.log("ii: "+ii);
                jsonArrayRespuesta[ii] = resMovies[0];
                console.log("jsonArrayRespuesta: "+JSON.stringify(jsonArrayRespuesta));//resMovies[0] is saved in jsonArrayRespuesta[2] both times
                console.log("length of jsonArrayRespuesta: "+jsonArrayRespuesta.length);//this shows 3, obviously...
            }//if-else
        });//Movies
    }//for
```

I'm confused because: 
-At one point inside the loop ii changes each iteration, but at other is always 2.
-2 is out of var ii = 0; ii <= res.length-1; but the program runs.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong and why? Thank you.

Comment: What is a "bucle"?

Comment: Your loop stops running by the time the callback function occurs. Read up on "closures" in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad the result of your sql query came and callback get called the for loop already finished running and value of ii reached to (res.length-1).

You can use clousere to solve this problem.

```
for(var ii = 0; ii <= res.length-1; ii++){
    console.log("res[ii].id: "+res[ii].id); //throws the correct message on console, so ii=1 first and later ii=2.

    (function(res,ii){
    laDatabase.all("SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Movies.id="+res[ii].id+";", function(err, resMovies){
        console.log("resMovies: "+JSON.stringify(resMovies)); //throws the correct message on console, the sql sentence is correct and runs without problem
        if(err){
            console.log("Error en 'SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Movies.id="+res[ii].id+";'");
            return;
        }else{
            //I tried to move the response of the sql query to the array I'll return. At this point, ii=2 always
            console.log("ii: "+ii);
            jsonArrayRespuesta[ii] = resMovies[0];
            console.log("jsonArrayRespuesta: "+JSON.stringify(jsonArrayRespuesta));//resMovies[0] is saved in jsonArrayRespuesta[2] both times
            console.log("length of jsonArrayRespuesta: "+jsonArrayRespuesta.length);//this shows 3, obviously...
        }//if-else
    });//Movies
 })(res,ii);

}//for
```